# What could be the reason for disallowing a sub query in the values clause?

Tags: oracle, subquery, database-internals

For example

```
SQL> create table dates(d date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into dates select sysdate from dual;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from dates;

D
---------
28-MAY-11

SQL> insert into dates (d) values (select sysdate fom dual);
insert into dates (d) values (select sysdate fom dual)
                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression


SQL>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use a SELECT statement where only a single value is allowed you need to put that SELECT statement into brackets:

```
insert into dates (d)
values
( (select sysdate from dual) )
```

That could be extended for multiple columns:

```
insert into dates 
(
  id, 
  d,
  other_column
)
values
( 
  some_sequence.nextval, 
  (select sysdate from dual), 
  (select max(some_col) from other_table)
)
```

You just need to make sure that the SELECT returns exactly one row and exactly one column

Comment: Why is the extra pair of brackets needed? Do they act like operators?

Comment: The brackets simply denotes a subquery. This syntax is specified in the SQL standard if I'm not totally mistaken (and works across most DBMS)

Comment: oddly, the `select` can return no rows without an error, in which case a `null` gets inserted, eg `insert into dates(d) values((select sysdate from dual where 1=2));`.

Comment: @Jack: yes, I think that's expected. If you'd use the same kind of subquery inside a select list, `NULL` is the only sensible "result" if the query returns nothing.

Comment: good point. I think I'd prefer to specify explicitly whether to error or insert `null` if that were possible, but if there is going to be a default that is the sensible one.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* without knowing (I don't do Oracle so don't have a box to try this on) that the problem is here:

```
insert into dates (d) values (select sysdate fom dual)
                              ^^^^^^ <- this isn't a date; it expects a date here
```

Try this instead:

```
insert into dates (d) 
select sysdate fom dual
```

Because the parenthesis tells the grammar that the value inside the paren is a value, not a value producing statement. I suppose, if you really want a more indepth explanation that I could go and look that up for you in the SQL language spec.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is just a historic fact.

**It is just not yet done that way.**

From SQL Server I know that they are releasing such restrictions between 2005 and 2008 and we often haven step into problems when we run such scripts on 2005.